# How to click <input type="text" > in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am having below mentioned code in which i want to click on a **`<input>`** type.

```
<div class="gwt-TabBarItem" tabindex="0" role="tab">
<div class="gwt-TabBarItem" tabindex="0" role="tab">
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
<div class="gwt-Label" style="white-space: nowrap;">Explore by Research Topic </div>
</div>
```

I want to click on `<input type="text" ....>`

I have tried all possible things like Click, WebElement Click, Java Script Click,sendkeys  etc.

But it is not working for me.
Do anyone have any solution for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What errors or exceptions are you seeing when you try the above mentioned methods? What do you expect to happen but doesn't?

Comment: One more thing i observed that    System.out.println( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gwt-TabBarItem']")).isDisplayed());  is giving true while    System.out.println( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gwt-TabBarItem']/input")).isDisplayed()); is giving false

Comment: Your `<input>` is ridiculously small (1px in widht and height). I don't think it's clickable with this size

Comment: xpath which worked for me is //div[contains(text(),'" + "Explore by Research Topic" + "')]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Selenium IDE, then use click command, with target as "css=input[type=text]". Should work. Selenium allows use of CSS selectors for locating elements. Examples of possible CSS selectors you can use are given here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Selenium WebDriver and even CSS selectors is not working which browser gives.

Comment: @AnuragMishra Could you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following Xpath:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Explore by Research Topic')]//preceding-sibling::input
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding code you provided the input field is hidden so you can't click it.
If this is not a temporary state and you still need to interact with it, try to change element opacity to displayed first - via JavaScript / jQuery.